# Why does Symfony escape & characters when using url_for()?

Tags: php, http, symfony1, uri

With this Symfony page, I am passing `$_GET` parameters in the URI like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/article?page=4&sort=1
```

Once in my layout, there are certain links in the page that need to have the same query string  in them.

Anyways, using Symfony's `url_for()` command I'm making URLs like so:

```
$url = url_for('article/index?.http_build_query($_GET));
```

That way it makes a new url using the $_GET variables. For some of the links I'm changing the $_GET values ahead of time, like `$_GET['sort']=0;` before generating the url. That's why I'm using this method.

Anyways, when I look at the generated URL, it now looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/article?page=4&amp%3Bsort=1
```

The `&amp%3B` is the encoded form of `&amp;` which is just an `&` character.

So the problem is that when I check for my $_GET parameters in my controller now, there is no longer a `sort` parameter that is passed. It's now called `&amp%3Bsort`... It's causing all sorts of issues.

Two questions:

1. How do I avoid this problem? Can I decode the `$_GET` parameter key values in my controller or something?
2. Why is symfony encoding a `&` character in the first place? It's a perfectly acceptable URI character. Heck, even the encoded value, `&amp%3B` contains a `&` !!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe, it is because of output escaping is ON in your application. As a result, $_GET array is wrapped inside sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator class. You can get a raw value using this: `$_GET->getRawValue()`.

```
$url = url_for('article/index?.http_build_query($_GET->getRawValue()))
```

Or you can decode the result query using sfOutputEscaper::unescape

```
$url = url_for('article/index?.sfOutputEscaper::unescape(http_build_query($_GET)));
```

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Best if you use Symfony's own method for getting the request parameters. For example, in templates, use:

```
$sf_request->getParameter('some_param');
```

If you must use $_GET, maybe try:

```
 (((    $sf_data->getRaw('_GET')   )))
```

... to get past the output escaping. Not totally sure if that'll work as is.

Comment: In my controller, I am using $request->getParameter(). It returns `&amp%3Bsort` as the parameter key.

Comment: @Jakobud: So, to get this right, you're first generating the URL in your action and passing it into the template, and once clicked, the parameters come back mangled. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry wasn't trying to be rude with the downvote. It just wasn't the answer. Yes I generate my url to be something like this: `$url = 'article/index?sort=true&whatever=false'` and after passing it into `url_for($url)` the url comes out like `http://www.mysite.com/article?sort=true&amp%3Bwhatever=false`. So now when my controller tries to read my parameters, the `whatever` parameter is now called the `&amp%3Bwhatever` parameter. Yes, even if I use `$request->getParameter()`.

Comment: Ok, the url helpers are meant mainly for templates (there are direct methods for actions, like generateUrl() etc. However, everything you pass from the actions to the templates gets escaped. Either get it as "raw" output in the template, or use the $sf_request object and parse that, or try wrapping the passed $url variable with html_entity_decode(). Basically, given that you now know it's an escaping problem, it should be fairly straightforward to work around it.